# Injective tensor product and extreme points

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces. Here $X \check \otimes Y$ menas injective tensor product of $X$ and $Y$. Is ext$B_{(X \check \otimes Y)^*}=\{x_{\alpha} \otimes y_{\alpha}: x_{\alpha} \in ext B_{X^*}, y_{\alpha} \in ext B_{Y^*}\}?$

Comment: Maybe you can explain a bit your notation?

Comment: @StefanWaldmann I imagine that B is the closed unit ball and ext is its set of extreme points

Answer (score 3):

Yes. See [The extreme points of certain spaces of operators](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01098901) by Tseitlin, or [Extreme points in the duals of operator spaces](https://eudml.org/doc/182904) by Ruess and Stegall for a more general result.